# Is there any method to implement linkedin login in reactjs?

Tags: reactjs, linkedin-api

I had tried many packages related to react linkedin login but not working. Can any one suggest other method for integrating linkedin login.

Comment: Could you specify what packages did you try to use and why exactly did it not work? This way we could perhaps solve the issue

Comment: "react-linkedin-login"
"react-linkedin-sdk"

Comment: Thats a package name, what about the issue?

Comment: Can't reslove react-linkedin-login? or it may be in redirect issue.

Answer (score 2):

Try React Linked In Login Using OAuth 2.0. Look at the documentation https://github.com/nvh95/react-linkedin-login-oauth2

Comment: I had tried it . The linkedin window is not appearing and the error shows like "You need to pass the "scope" parameter". How can I pass the scope parameter?

Answer (score 1):

Your answer has 2 things:

1. use https://github.com/nvh95/react-linkedin-login-oauth2 like daniel suggested
2. define scope parameter depending on your app but in general it can be:
   scope="r_emailaddress,r_liteprofile"

put this in the  Component